# Handling dynamic arguments from $.when in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have ajax requests in my `requests` array. The number of requests could be 1,2 or 3 (does not matter, dynamically).

The requests like this:

```
var ajaxRequest = $.get(ajaxUrl, requestData);
```

I am want to process the results like this:

```
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function () {
    $.each(arguments, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value);
        //var response = JSON.parse(value[0]); //It is fail if there is only 1 ajax request
    });
});
```

The problem is the `arguments`.

If there is only 1 request, than at the each, the values will be

```
string [the json string, what I want to JSON.parse]
string ['success']
Object [the Ajax request Object]
```

In this case the arguments length is 3, this will cause problems later.

But, if I have 2 or 3 requests, then I will get back arrays like this, (for example for 2 requests):

```
Array [json string, 'success', ajax Object],
Array [json string, 'success', ajax Object]
```

If three requests, of course one more array.

And the problem is here. I can not check the length of arguments, because it is 3 if I have 3 requests, and 3 if I have only one requests.

So I rewrote my script like this:

```
$.each(arguments, function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        var response = JSON.parse(value);
    } else {
        var response = JSON.parse(value[0]);
    }
    $('div[data-id="' + response.productId + '"').find('.dictionaryContainer').find('ul').html(response.html);
});
```

Now my problem is here:

```
if (typeof value === 'string') {
```

even if it is good, the iteration is continuous, maybe it could be hacked somehow with flags, and `return ture`s, but I bet, there is some more elegant solution for this.

Can anybody help me to handle this?

Comment: Ok, I think, I need to check the `arguments` variable before the `$.each`. Now I am working on this.

Comment: Yes, this will be the solution. Before `$.each` I check, if `arguments[0]` is exists, and if yes, and this is a string, then just 1 request has sent, but if it is an object, I need to use `$.each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple work around would be to check the length of requests yourself and adjust what you're iterating on, something like this:

```
$.when.apply(null, requests).done(function() {
 var arg = (requests.length === 1) ? [arguments] : arguments;
 $.each(arg, function(i, response) {
   console.log(response);
 })
});
```

Something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46o1udqe/1/)

Comment: That's a nice, simple, direct approach, looking at `requests` to know whether to fix-up the arguments. Suggested tweak: `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); `var arg = requests.length === 1 ? [args] : args;` just so things are reliably arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as you've found, the combination of `$.when` and the kind of promise is essentially broken because of its chaotic behavior that depends on whether you pass one or two+ arguments to `$.when`.

I'd suggest either:

1. Using promises (with a polyfill if needed) and promise-ifying `$.ajax`, `$.get`, etc.; then use `Promise.all` on the array of promises.
2. Implementing your own `$.whenAll` that isn't chaotic.

Here are rough version of both (just for `$.ajax`, you can do your own `$.get` and `$.post` readily enough):

Rough version of #1: *(Note: Creating a new, clean promise rather than reusing `$.ajax`'s promise in order to* just *return the result [not `success`'s other arguments] and return a single object with a rejection [not `error`'s various discrete arguments].)*

```
$.promiseAjax = function(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        options = $.extend({}, {
            success: function(result) {
                resolve(result);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                reject({
                    jqXHR: jqXHR,
                    textStatus: textStatus,
                    errorThrown: errorThrown
                });
            }
        }, options);
        $.ajax(options);
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
var requests = [];
if (someCondition) {
    requests.push($.promiseAjax({/*...*/}));
}
if (someotherCondition) {
    requests.push($.promiseAjax({/*...*/}));
}
Promise.all(requests).then(function(results) {
    // `results` will reliably be an array of the results, even when
    // there's only one request
});
```

Rough version of #2:

```
$.whenAll = function(promises) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var results = [];
    var counter = promises.length;
    promises.forEach(function(promise, index) {
        promise
            .done(function(result) {
            results[index] = result;
            if (--counter == 0) {
              // All done
                d.resolve(results);
            }
          })
          .fail(function() {
            d.reject(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
          });
    });
    return d.promise();
};
```

usge:

```
var requests = [];
if (someCondition) {
    requests.push($.ajax({/*...*/}));
}
if (someotherCondition) {
    requests.push($.ajax({/*...*/}));
}
$.whenAll(requests).then(function(results) {
    // `results` will reliably be an array of the results, even when
    // there's only one request
});
```

Comment: I will check these solutions later, second seems more clear to me. Now I solved with my solution, what is check the `arguments[0]`. If that is a string, then `JSON.parse(arguments[0])`, else iterate on each arguments. Yes, I know, it is not safe, and do not handle fails, but for now it's ok me, later I will go deep down into your second solution. Thank you.

Comment: @karacsi_maci: If you're looking for a minimal, one-off solution, take a look at [T J's updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41441511/157247), which uses a nice, simple, direct approach to dealing with the ambiguity. About the answer above: Proper promises are the way forward for things like this, where we want to wait for a bunch of parallel ops to finish (and some other forms of composition). (When just doing a bunch of async things in series they're the current way, but will probably give way to `async`/`await` in a couple of years.)